# How do I deal with a question with a user who intends on breaking TOS of a specific API?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, ethics

I have come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62232664/discord-py-selfbot-cant-get-guild-users/) where a user is asking for help in self-botting in Discord in the [discord.py] tag which is an API wrapper for the Discord API.

Self-botting is explicitly against the [Discord guidelines](https://discord.com/guidelines) as @Oblique [has already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239294/12002411).

How does one deal with such a question? Should I flag it and if so, as what?

Comment: Why do you feel that something more needs to be done, beyond the clear answer that was provided?

Comment: @CodyGray  I assumed that questions like these sometimes also get answers (from well-meaning people who don't know any better) without regards to the TOS, creating a situation where Stackoverflow hosts information to get around the TOS which I also assume is against the sitewide ethics.

Comment: A safer assumption is that if it isn't specifically documented to be against the rules, it's allowed. Stack Overflow is a knowledge base, hosting knowledge is not the same as abusing knowledge. Any code present in the site can be part of Skynet.